# Tengo problemas con copiado en Batch

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

Tengo un directorio en windows repleto de archivos txt, todos numerados consecutivamente (ejemplo: f1,f2,f3 ,etc) son mas de 2 millones de ellos, lo que necesito es un script que copie cada 400 archivos y cree una carpeta con nombre numerico (ejemplo: folder1, folder2, folder3, etc), para copiar los siguientes 400 archivos, tengo el siguiente script, el problema es que me copia todo a una sola carpeta que crea

```
@echo off

rem COUNT
set c=0

rem FOLDER ID
set f=0

mkdir folder%f%
echo Copiando a folder%f%...

for %%i in (*) do (
  if %%c LSS 400 (
    rem COPY TO CURRENT FOLDER
    copy %%i folder%f%\

    rem INCREASE ITERATION COUNT
    set /a c+=1
  ) else (
    rem INCREASE FOLDER ID
    set /a f+=1

    rem ADD A NEW FOLDER
    mkdir folder%f%
    echo Copiando a folder%f%...

    rem RESET ITERATION COUNT
    set c=0
  )
)
```

Comment: nadie puede ayudarme? no le encuentro solucion

Comment: no he trabajado en esto en mucho tiempo, pero deja que lo mire y te comento en un ratito si encuentro solución. Mientras tanto completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set start=1
set end=400
set filecount=0


::Contar archivos en carpeta
    for /r %~dp0 %%A in (*.*) do (
        set /a filecount+=1
        )
    set /a filecount-=1
    set /a foldnumber=%filecount% / %end%
    set /a sobra=%filecount% %%%end%
    if not %sobra%==0 (set /a foldnumber+=1)

::Copiar archivos
for /l %%A in (1,1,%foldnumber%) do (
    mkdir folder%%A
    for /l %%B in (!start!,1,!end!) do (
        xcopy "f%%B.txt" folder%%A
    )
    set /a start+=400
    set /a end+=400
)
```

He creado esta script que se encarga de ordenar de 400 en 400 los archivos f%numero%.txt en carpetas numericamente, espero que te sirva.

Comment: La persona que hizo la pregunta no necesita ordenar los archivos. Necesita un script que copie cada 400 archivos y cree una carpeta con nombre numérico (ejemplo: folder1, folder2, folder3, etc…).

Comment: Entonces simplemente habría que cambiar el comando move por xcopy

Comment: Supongo. Edita la respuesta con lo que quien preguntó necesita.

Comment: Te amo! muchas gracias era exactamente eso :) me lleve tiempo editando y dandole vuelta sin resultado, Tu solucion es la correcta, una vez mas. MUCHAS GRACIAS